# Sum function in VBA (number and string)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, sum

Have a problem with summing cells in vba using =sum(number, string) function.

Here is an example, that is working in regular excel: **sum(5, A1)**

But it doesn't work via VBA formula - asking for a number instead of a string. Is there a way to use **=sum(5, A1)** in VBA?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value into a variable?  are you trying to insert the formula in a cell with vba?  there are many question that would be answered if you showed what you tried.

Comment: You mean... like `yourVariable = 5 + Range("A5").Value` ?  Or like `Range("A2").Value = 5 + Range("A5").Value`... what are you asking here? There is not much correlation between Excel formulas and VBA so the question is sort of nonsensical a bit.

Comment: Trying to insert formula in a cell with vba

Comment: Set a formula for a cell in VBA: `Range("A2").Formula = "=Sum(5,A1)"`

Comment: JNevill, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(5, Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

[image]

or as JNevill points out:

```
Sub dural2()
    MsgBox Evaluate("SUM(5,A1)")
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Here are some alternatives:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(5, [A1])
    MsgBox 5 + [A1]
End Sub
```

To put a formula in a cell, say cell **B9**, use:

```
Sub PutFormulaInCell()
    Range("B9").Formula = "=SUM(5,A1)"
End Sub
```